# How to debug an Oracle query given an explain plan?

Tags: sql, oracle

[IMAGE OF TOAD: query waits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xa2wy.png)

```
WITH 
    NJ AS  (SELECT CNATJUR  FROM RE_CD.CDTD005_NATUR_JURIDICA  WHERE DESCRICAO = 'Particulares'  AND DTEND_VER   = '9999-12-31 00:00'  ),  
    PAISES AS  (SELECT PAIS_BST  FROM RE_CD.CDTD006_PAISES  WHERE GRUPO_PAIS = 'RESTO UNIAO EUROPEIA'  AND DTEND_VER    = '9999-12-31 00:00'  ),  
    GAR AS  (SELECT  /*+PARALLEL(4)*/  CCONTA,    CREFERENCIA_IMP  FROM RE_DM.DMTD002_GAR_CONTRATO  WHERE TIPO_GAR      = 'GAR REAL'  AND TIPO_GAR2       = 'GAR DINERARIA'  AND FLAG_PRIORIDADE = 1  AND IDVERSAO        =    (SELECT MAX(IDVERSAO)    FROM RE_DM.DMTD001_VERSOES    WHERE TABELA  = 'RE_DM.DMTD002_GAR_CONTRATO'    AND DTEND_VER = '9999-12-31 00:00'    )  )

    SELECT    /*+PARALLEL(4)*/    MOROS.COD_PERIMETRO,    MOROS.SOCIEDADE 
    FROM RE_DM.DMTF020_MOROS MOROS 
      INNER JOIN GAR    ON MOROS.CCONTA = GAR.CCONTA AND MOROS.CREFERENCIA = GAR.CREFERENCIA_IMP 
      INNER JOIN NJ     ON MOROS.COD_NATJUR = NJ.CNATJUR 
      INNER JOIN PAISES ON MOROS.COD_PAIS = PAISES.PAIS_BST
    WHERE MOROS.IDVERSAO                = 167
      AND MOROS.SEGMENTO <>  'PC'  AND MOROS.SEGMENTO <>  'LO'   AND MOROS.SEGMENTO <>  'GA' 
      AND MOROS.SEGMENTO <>  'G1' AND MOROS.SEGMENTO <>  'G2' AND MOROS.SEGMENTO <>  'G3'
      AND MOROS.INPUT                     = 'IMP'
      AND MOROS.FLAG_MOROSIDADE           = 0;

   Plan hash value: 441958758

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                        | Name                   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |    TQ  |IN-OUT| PQ Distrib |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                 |                        | 76752 |    16M| 22115   (1)| 00:01:07 |        |      |            |
|   1 |  PX COORDINATOR                  |                        |       |       |            |          |        |      |            |
|   2 |   PX SEND QC (RANDOM)            | :TQ20002               | 76752 |    16M| 22113   (1)| 00:01:07 |  Q2,02 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |
|*  3 |    HASH JOIN                     |                        | 76752 |    16M| 22113   (1)| 00:01:07 |  Q2,02 | PCWP |            |
|   4 |     PX RECEIVE                   |                        |    42 |  1512 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q2,02 | PCWP |            |
|   5 |      PX SEND BROADCAST           | :TQ20000               |    42 |  1512 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q2,00 | P->P | BROADCAST  |
|   6 |       PX BLOCK ITERATOR          |                        |    42 |  1512 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q2,00 | PCWC |            |
|*  7 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL         | CDTD006_PAISES         |    42 |  1512 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q2,00 | PCWP |            |
|*  8 |     HASH JOIN                    |                        |   237K|    41M| 22110   (1)| 00:01:07 |  Q2,02 | PCWP |            |
|   9 |      PX RECEIVE                  |                        |    23 |  1150 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q2,02 | PCWP |            |
|  10 |       PX SEND BROADCAST          | :TQ20001               |    23 |  1150 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q2,01 | P->P | BROADCAST  |
|  11 |        PX BLOCK ITERATOR         |                        |    23 |  1150 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q2,01 | PCWC |            |
|* 12 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL        | CDTD005_NATUR_JURIDICA |    23 |  1150 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q2,01 | PCWP |            |
|  13 |      NESTED LOOPS                |                        |       |       |            |          |  Q2,02 | PCWP |            |
|  14 |       NESTED LOOPS               |                        |   795K|   100M| 22105   (1)| 00:01:07 |  Q2,02 | PCWP |            |
|  15 |        PX BLOCK ITERATOR         |                        |       |       |            |          |  Q2,02 | PCWC |            |
|* 16 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL        | DMTD002_GAR_CONTRATO   |  6357 |   341K|  4423   (1)| 00:00:14 |  Q2,02 | PCWP |            |
|  17 |          SORT AGGREGATE          |                        |     1 |    42 |            |          |  Q2,02 | PCWP |            |
|  18 |           PX COORDINATOR         |                        |       |       |            |          |        |      |            |
|  19 |            PX SEND QC (RANDOM)   | :TQ10000               |     1 |    42 |            |          |  Q1,00 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |
|  20 |             SORT AGGREGATE       |                        |     1 |    42 |            |          |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|  21 |              PX BLOCK ITERATOR   |                        |     1 |    42 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | PCWC |            |
|* 22 |               TABLE ACCESS FULL  | DMTD001_VERSOES        |     1 |    42 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|* 23 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN          | DMTF020_MOROS_INDEX2   |    21 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q2,02 | PCWP |            |
|* 24 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| DMTF020_MOROS          |   125 |  9750 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q2,02 | PCWP |            |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - access("MOROS"."COD_PAIS"="PAIS_BST")
   7 - filter("GRUPO_PAIS"='RESTO UNIAO EUROPEIA' AND "DTEND_VER"='9999-12-31 00:00')
   8 - access("MOROS"."COD_NATJUR"="CNATJUR")
  12 - filter("DESCRICAO"='Particulares' AND "DTEND_VER"='9999-12-31 00:00')
  16 - filter("TIPO_GAR2"='GAR DINERARIA' AND "TIPO_GAR"='GAR REAL' AND "FLAG_PRIORIDADE"=1 AND "IDVERSAO"= (SELECT 
              MAX(SYS_OP_CSR(SYS_OP_MSR(MAX("IDVERSAO")),0)) FROM "RE_DM"."DMTD001_VERSOES" "DMTD001_VERSOES" WHERE 
              "TABELA"='RE_DM.DMTD002_GAR_CONTRATO' AND "DTEND_VER"='9999-12-31 00:00'))
  22 - filter("TABELA"='RE_DM.DMTD002_GAR_CONTRATO' AND "DTEND_VER"='9999-12-31 00:00')
  23 - access("MOROS"."CREFERENCIA"="CREFERENCIA_IMP")
       filter("MOROS"."CREFERENCIA" IS NOT NULL)
  24 - filter("MOROS"."IDVERSAO"=167 AND "MOROS"."CCONTA" IS NOT NULL AND TO_NUMBER("MOROS"."FLAG_MOROSIDADE")=0 AND 
              "MOROS"."INPUT"='IMP' AND "MOROS"."SEGMENTO"<>'GA' AND "MOROS"."SEGMENTO"<>'G1' AND "MOROS"."SEGMENTO"<>'PC' AND 
              "MOROS"."SEGMENTO"<>'G2' AND "MOROS"."SEGMENTO"<>'G3' AND "MOROS"."SEGMENTO"<>'LO' AND "MOROS"."CCONTA"="CCONTA")

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=5)
   - Degree of Parallelism is 4 because of hint
```

Does anyone see something fishy with this "explain plan"? I've added indexes, I ran statistics, rebuild indexes... the server is a laptop with 8gb ram, SSD hard drive and i7 cpu.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please generate the plan again and include **the whole** plan in the question. There is no "predicate information" that is printed below the plan's table. Use `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR your_query` and then `SELECT * FROM Table( DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY )` commands to generate the plan.

Comment: Explain plan added to original post.

Comment: `TO_NUMBER("MOROS"."FLAG_MOROSIDADE")=0 ` => this means, that  `FLAG_MOROSIDADE` is of VARCHAR or CHAR datatype, but the query is comparing it with a number `0`, and an implicit conversion occurs. Please rewrite this conndition to `MOROS.FLAG_MOROSIDADE='0'`, this will eliminate the implicit conversion. This also allows Oracle for using an index on this column (it such the index is created).

Comment: Will check and retry. Thank you for your reply.
Edit: confirmed. Changed and retesting.

Comment: Next time this happens use real-time SQL monitoring to find out what operation is slow and what event it's waiting on.  Use a query like this: `select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor('use the SQL_ID for the statement') from dual;`.  If temporary tablespace was the problem you might see lots of waits for things like 'tempfile write'.  The Toad query waits only show you the current waits, SQL monitoring show you all the waits during the run.

Comment: Thank you for the tip :)

Comment: To mark a question as solved, please accept an answer below, by clicking the tick mark to the left of the answer so it turns green. If there is no suitable answer you may create one yourself (I have done this for you).

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, look for your full table scans, but they aren't always the culprit.  The problem appears to be in the nested loops.

I would focus on DMTD002_GAR_CONTRATO, and perhaps place an index to eliminate the 
full table scan; however, I suspect that the main problem may be in the subquery in the where clause that creates table alias "GAR".

It would be worth experimenting with a hardcoded value rather than a subquery to see if it improves performance.

Comment: Will try that. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of OP).*

Our temp tablespace was super tiny. After increasing the size all things start to go faster and smoother. Thanks to all that helped.